# Failing to store agents with multiprocessing.Queue

Tags: parallel-processing, multiprocessing, queue

I try to parallelize a simulation by splitting it into several processes. In each process, I simulate N agents over T periods. For one agent and one period this is just

```
ag.step()
```

, where **ag** is an instance of the agent class. My worker looks like this:

```
class Worker(mp.Process):
    def __init__(self, args):
        mp.Process.__init__(self, args = args)
        self.agents = []
        self.N = args[0]
        self.T = args[1]
        self.q = args[2]

    def run(self):
        for i in range(N):
            ag = agent()
            for t in range(T):
                ag.step()   
            self.agents.append(ag)
        self.q.put(self.agents)
```

Then I just do

```
q = mp.Queue()
if __name__ == '__main__':    
    processes, p = [], []
    
    for i in range(mp.cpu_count()):
        p = Worker(args = (N,T,q))
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)
    
    for p in processes:
        p.join()
```

However, when I try to get my simulated agents with

```
q.get()
```

it does not work, this line keeps running for a very long time. But if I store not instances of the agent class but some particular results of simulation, like doing

```
self.agents.append(ag.state)
```

instead, then it works well and q.get() returns a list of values. Why it that?

My N and T are very small (say, 10 and 10) now, but the agent class is relatively complicated (each agent has a neural network, memory, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this happened because objects to put in the queue should be pickable. To some extent, I managed to fix it by using **pathos.multiprocessing** instead.